# How can I add several clickable links at once in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, url

How can I add several clickable links at once in Microsoft Word?

E.g., I want to be able to convert the following

[image]

into

[image]

at once, i.e. without having to make each link clickable one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Word VBA - Converting All Plain Text Links to Hyperlinks](http://superuser.com/questions/1061333/ms-word-vba-converting-all-plain-text-links-to-hyperlinks)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The OP of the other question seems to want to use VBA. I am open to anything.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That's incorrect, see the answer below ( which luckily was written before my question got closed… )

Comment: Feel free to request it be reopened.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'll first focus on avoiding it being closed. Did you retract your close vote?

Comment: Ahh, you said "before my question got closed" so I assumed it got closed already. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do **AutoFormat Now** using Alt-Ctrl-K (or locate it and put it in the QAT), but it will apply *all* the AutoFormat rules that you currently have specified.

You can also put the Autoformat... option in the QAT. When you click that option, you get an option to Autoformat Now and Review each change, and a button that takes you to the various Autoformat/correct option dialog panes. However, the Autoformat... dialog box is tied up with a (deprecated?) feature that tried to format your document depending on what type of document you said it is, so you may end up with more change than you bargained for. Also, rather than stepping through and asking you *before* it makes each change, Word makes use of the track changes feature, which you may not really want to use in that way.

---

In Microsoft Word 2010 and 2013, AutoFormat rules can be found in:

[image]

[image]

In Word 2007 click the Office button and then click Word Options. In Microsoft Word 97, 2000, 2002, and 2003, choose AutoCorrect from the Tools menu.