# How select all text and convert each html into a link Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a table with a bunch of URL's to files on my computer that are in plain text. I want to auto convert all of them into url links so it is easier for me to open the link from Excel rather than copying and pasting into a browser each time. I found a [macro from a different post](https://superuser.com/questions/1061333/converting-all-plain-text-links-to-hyperlinks) in Word but how can I do it in Excel?

For example:

```
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1339
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1196
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1115
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1032
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1027
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1024
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1036
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-994
file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-782
```

should look something like this but with file instead of http and no numbers:

1. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1339
2. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1196
3. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1115
4. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1032
5. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1027
6. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1024
7. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-1036
8. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-994
9. http:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-782

Update: I have tried `=HYPERLINK()` but that just gives me error `The formula you typed contains an error.`

Comment: you can use `HYPERLINK` function of Excel.

Comment: Please share the HYPERLINK formula you used.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that should be done with a short visual basic script:

1. Run through all the cells and look for ones that start with "https"
2. Cut the contents of the cell
3. Re-write the contents using the "HYPERLINK" function and include the URL you just cut

It's simply finding the syntax to use to do all of this. If you need help with Visual Basic syntax for Excel, you can go over to StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you show what the formula looks like once you've added it. It seems like it's a syntax error and not a function error.

Comment: You are certainly missing some commas. Try this: =HYPERLINK("file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-782")

Comment: Also, are you trying to link to a website or an actual file? Because either way your syntax is off

Comment: I believe you mean add quotes to put: `=HYPERLINK("file:///issues%20apache/jira/browse/CONN-782") ` the result says `cannot find the specified file`. I found that by replacing the %20 with a space fixed the problem.